# Android scale/translate canvas with images

Tags: android, image-processing, dictionary, android-canvas, gesture

I want to develop an Android application that has an inapp map. The application gives information to the users, and there will be a screen where I want to show an indoor map with pins of a building. So for example if the user reads a short text about a coffee machine there will be a button, and if the user clicks on it, the app shows a floorplan (map of the building) with pins, and zooms to the coffee machine pin. If the user clicks on an other pin, a new screen comes up (without the map) and shows some details information (with a button to go back to the map)

So I want:

- zoom, translate, rotate (by gestures) an image (map)
- put clickable pins on it (custom pins)

First I find the Google maps indoor: http://maps.google.com/help/maps/floorplans/
But it's in beta, and I only want to show the building map. And it's not too good...

I started implement a rotate, scale and translate capable view, but it's not easy to handle pins. The pins should be stay on the right places, and if you rotate the map the pins should not rotate, and the pins should be clickable.

Then I find this library: https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/
I started with the photo demo, but I still have problems with the pins. They don't stay in position. Can somebody show me an example with static position pins?

Am I on a wrong way to do this map? Is there somebody with experience? Do you think I should work with this multitouch contoroller?